# CSS margin auto not centering

Tags: css, margin, centering

I have simplified the code as much as possible, but still can't get it to center. I believe my inexperience with `CSS` is not allowing me to see something extremely simple.

If anyone also knows some good resources for css, that'll be great. I have read sections of many `CSS` books but there all very basic and cover the same thing.

**CSS Markup:**

```
/* MAIN ––––––––––––––––––––– */
html {
    /* overflow-y:scroll; */
}
body {
    /* margin:0; */
    /* position:relative; */
}
/* Form ––––––––––––––––––––– */
#form {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>

    <form id='form'></form>

  </body>
</hml>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the display to block if you want to use margin:auto for centering.  That does not work with inline elements.

Comment: Text-align:center works on inline and inline-block elements if you need to mix inline and block then you could use that.