# Display image and title on same height in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display an image on the left or right corner and the title in the center on same height. I tried the following code, however, I get the image and title on two different heights. I want to display both side by side.

**server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

})
```

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    headerPanel( title=div(img(src="bigorb.png",  height = 100, width = 100),
                           h3("Image Display Test", align="center", style="bold")
                           ))
    )
  ))
```

and it displays 
[image]

Comment: headerPanel( title=div(img(src="bigorb.png",  height = 100, width = 100),
                           "Image Display Test"))

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                        tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom-div.css"),
  h3(
    div(style="display:inline-block;",img(src="bigorb.png", height = 150, width = 150,style="left;")),
    div(id="smile","Image Display Test")
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("length",
                "Enter your length:"),
      textInput("weight",
                "Enter your weigth:")
    ),
      mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("testHTML")
    )
  )
))
```

and the .css file. You can find all info that you need about .css file in shiny R [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

```
#smile {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

I hope it works for you all and keep coding! 
PS: I just followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802728/css-margin-auto-not-centering)

Comment: All right, I'am going to edit my answer, just a sec.